# My react component timer doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to use the `Header` Component as a Clock timer. I hope my page rendering per one sec. I followed some example in google search. But, couldn't find example like this.
Why doesn't this `tick()` function work?
There are no errors in the console.

This is my first code:

```
class index extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
constructor({ title }: Props) {
    super({ title });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Layout title={this.props.title}>
            <div className="header"><Header/></div>
            <div className="search-bar"><SearchBar/></div>
            <div className="Footer"><Footer/></div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
}
```

Second code:

```
class Header extends React.Component<{}, States>{
intervalID: any;
constructor() {
    super({}, {});
    this.state = {
        date: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    } 
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
}

tick() {
    this.setState({
        date: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <header>
            <p>Header: {this.state.date}</p>
        </header>
    );
}
}

export default Header;
```

This code (Node.js router) calls `First` page. `App` uses 'express-react-view' for its view engine.

```
import { Request, Response }  from "express";

/**
* Get /
* Home page.
* @param req 
* @param res 
*/
export let index = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   res.render("index", {"title": "React, Front-end"})
};
```

Comment: There is any error in console ? please add error

Comment: What is that `States` type in your second code?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry "NO ERROR" in console. Here is States type in 2nd code. interface States {
    date: string;
}

Comment: Could you show us how are you using your first component?

Comment: Sure! I don't know what was wrong..

Comment: I think that this is related to your component name (index).. React components should start with an uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing server-side rendering (that's what `express-react-view` does), which means the lifecycle hooks of your React components will not be called.

Thus, the interval trigger on `componentDidMount()` won't be called. [This article](https://jaketrent.com/post/react-componentdidmount-not-called-server-render/) has a good explanation for why this is.

Comment: O, I understand.